# Does any know if cucumber can support HSF API automation? or Any tool can support HSF Api Automation

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

I would like to automate HSF API. Does cucumber support it or is there any tool that can support it.

Comment: Are HSF API built on REST principles?
Please note - Cucumber is framework to write your feature. In turn with your step definition you can write code to test anything. 
Cucumber is agnostic of UI or API Testing.

Comment: Yes its agnostic, but we would need a particular gem to support the HSF automation.